# Populating ListBox.DataTextField

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have an asp:Listbox with the DataSource set to `Logic.Coms`. This is a list object that contains several `Company` objects. If `Company` has a property of `CompName`, how do I set ListBox.DataTextField to display that name without breaking the integrity of click-to-select?
In this instance, selecting an entry in the listbox will reference the `Company` object in order to display its properties in another tab.

For reference, this is what I have so far:

```
logic.createQuery(nameBox.Text, "companyName");
foreach (Objects.Company c in logic.coms)
      {
           resultsListBox.DataSource = logic.coms;
           resultsListBox.DataTextField = //???
      } 
resultsListBox.DataBind();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney thanks, I missed that from an earlier experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataTextField` property to the field you want to display:

```
<asp:ListBox DataTextField="CompName" ... />
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4d7ktzs(v=vs.90).aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle):

> Use the [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.90).aspx) and [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield(v=vs.90).aspx) properties to specify which field in the data source to bind to the `Text` and `Value` properties, respectively, of each list item in the control.

For anyone familiar with desktop development, these are equivalent to `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

---

To set it in code-behind (as you've indicated you need to do), give the control an ID:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="MyListBox" ... />
```

And set the same property:

```
MyListBox.DataTextField = "CompName";
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in the code-behind? I have no reference in the code-behind file for `CompName`, and I will need to re-use the listbox for lists of other kinds of objects.

Comment: erm... I'm not too sure I understand. I'll make a better edit to my original post.

Comment: So the datatextfield doesn't need a physical reference, rather it is similar to a connection string in that It's simply a string? Edit: no good, it doesn't work.